# Failed to fetch while error reading CSV file ASP.NET

Tags: csv, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm trying to read `.CSV` file and instead of the read lines, Swagger outputs

> Failed to fetch.
> Possible Reasons:
>
> CORS
> Network Failure
> URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

In my opinion, even Visual Studio crashed, the application immediately stops working

```
//Controller
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController: ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ICSVService _csvService;

    public HomeController(ICSVService csvService)
    {
        _csvService = csvService;
    }

    [HttpPost("read-csv")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCSV([FromForm] IFormFileCollection file)
    {
        var dataFromFile = _csvService.ReadCSV<Values>(file[0].OpenReadStream());

        return Ok(dataFromFile);
    }
}

// Reader
public class CSVServise : ICSVService
{
    public IEnumerable<T> ReadCSV<T>(Stream file)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(file);
        var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var records = csv.GetRecords<T>();
        return records;
    }
}

// Program.cs
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms /aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICSVService, CSVServise>();
builder.Services.AddCors();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

[My launchSettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7J0p.png)

I thought enabling CORS would help, but it doesn't seem to have worked. And now I have no idea - what could be the problem?

Comment: What is the error message on the Console tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: POST https://localhost:44330/Home/read-csv net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Couple of things need to check to answer your concern. Firstly, how you are calling this API? I mean from from where? Hows your `launchSettings.json` looks like? How many URL you have set on `launchSettings.json` these infromation would need to investigate your issue.

Comment: I add settings by picture and i tried to lauch both as IIS and Core App (Infotex)

Comment: I found that the file does not open at the endpoint, in principle, regardless of the method signature. I still don't understand what the problem is. If i open stream with csvHelper by Folder - all is Ok. But it couldnt post file by swagger.